# Multi-select in jQuery not working even after the addition of the dependancies in a right format as mentioned in the multi-select Tutorial

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, checkbox, multi-select

[image: image reference for multi-select]I am trying with the multi select with check box plugin of jQuery as suggested in the following link 
http://davidstutz.de/bootstrap-multiselect/#getting-started
But while i implemented at js fiddle for testing means doesnt work as expected, what would be the issue here 
This is the link to js fiddle test code

```js
$('select[multiple]').multiselect();
$('#langOpt').multiselect({
    columns: 1,
    placeholder: 'Select Languages',
    search: true
});
```

```html
<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- MultiSelect CSS & JS library -->
<link href="multiselect/jquery.multiselect.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="multiselect/jquery.multiselect.js"></script>
<select name="langOpt[]" multiple id="langOpt">
    <option value="C++">C++</option>
    <option value="C#">C#</option>
    <option value="Java">Java</option>
    <option value="Objective-C">Objective-C</option>
    <option value="JavaScript">JavaScript</option>
    <option value="Perl">Perl</option>
    <option value="PHP">PHP</option>
    <option value="Ruby on Rails">Ruby on Rails</option>
    <option value="Android">Android</option>
    <option value="iOS">iOS</option>
    <option value="HTML">HTML</option>
    <option value="XML">XML</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Without seeing some code then we can't tell you what's wrong and can't solve it for you.

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen, sorry added the code now

Comment: try change multiselect to multiSelect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your post you said you were using the jQuery plugin, and you did use it in your code, but the link and image are for the bootstrap-multiselect, they are different. I assume your are trying to use the bootstrap plugin from the start, I've changed the answer to bootstrap-multiselect.

```js
$('select[multiple]').multiselect();
```

```html
<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap -->
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"> 
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- MultiSelect CSS & JS library -->
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-multiselect/0.9.15/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-multiselect/0.9.15/js/bootstrap-multiselect.min.js"></script>
<select name="langOpt[]" multiple id="langOpt">
    <option value="C++">C++</option>
    <option value="C#">C#</option>
    <option value="Java">Java</option>
    <option value="Objective-C">Objective-C</option>
    <option value="JavaScript">JavaScript</option>
    <option value="Perl">Perl</option>
    <option value="PHP">PHP</option>
    <option value="Ruby on Rails">Ruby on Rails</option>
    <option value="Android">Android</option>
    <option value="iOS">iOS</option>
    <option value="HTML">HTML</option>
    <option value="XML">XML</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Hey thanks @Francisco Marão, but i want it as per check boxes under a select, i have attached an image to my post above please check and help me with that.

Comment: Sorry, only now I noticed that you are mixing things up, in your post you said you were using the jQuery plugin, and you did use it in your code, but the link and image are for the bootstrap-multiselect, they are different. I assume your are trying to use the bootstrap plugin from the start, I've changed the answer to bootstrap-multiselect?

Comment: this works on  a js fiddle editor, but at my template doesnt seem to, i am trying to integrate this at text box field with select dropdown, unable to add my code here could you please suggest me a way to add that part of the code so i could show you and seek assistance on my issue.